# Move CCSprite around another CCSprite Circle Shape

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

[image]

We have CCSprite Circle A and CCSprite Circle B.

Move Circle B around Circle A. I already tried to create a CCNode and attach the circle B to it. In this case it works perfectly but the position is constant also. I need to move the circle around A and update the position. I will have more objects on the screen and I will check if B intersect some other objects, but for that case I need to update the position while rotating. Much appreciate your help guys. I am using Cocos2D v3.0

Comment: This parent-child solution is the way to go. For collision detection you can use convertToNodeSpace and convertToWorldSpace to get absolute coordinates of the rotated position. Also if you need bounding box collisions you can simply use the boundingBox property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Put this in your update method. I used this code in my box2d project for orbit. Change it for your needs.

```
    b2Vec2 center = bodyA->GetPosition();
    int smoothness = 1000;
    int radius = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < smoothness; i++) {
        float angle = (i / smoothness) * 360 * DEGTORAD;

        b2Vec2 pos( sinf(angle), cosf(angle));
        b2Vec2 newposition = center + radius * pos;

        bodyB->SetTransform(newposition, bodyB->GetAngle());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the anchor point of B in the position of the anchor point of A and then rotate the B by 360 in animation.