# How to apply Orbital Gravity in cocos2d chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gravity, orbital-mechanics

I am building an IOS game in Cocos2d - Chipmunk - Spritebuilder. I need to make  a characters orbit around  around a point, and I was having quite some difficulty in implementing orbits with real physics. 
So far, I have tried two methods, one is creating a distance joint from the player to the planet, and then applying a 90 degree force on the player where an angle is created between the end of the distance joint and an imaginary line drawn at a 90 angle to it. He moves around crazily and this method is not working for me.

I then tried calculating 180 points on the circumference at a radius from the planet (which is the bounds of detecting and implementing its effects on the player) - and then in a scheduled update method [character.physicsbody applyForce:nextCircumferencePoint]; This does not work, as he does not follow the path exactly and is quite far from it. I am thinking that I need to also apply a gravitational force towards the planet which would cause him to circle it. Though I don't know how to calculate that force, apply it, or if it would even help.

A third method which would never work, but was used for  testing was to set his position to the next circumference point. He does orbit, but any collision won't work (such as if a piece of space junk goes in his way.) He will simply be positioned right over any other object. This world great if you don't need collisions, are writing your own physics engine. This is not a polished way of doing things, so will avoid it.

Please correct anything I have already done and tell me how it would work, or shed light on other options and how to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754969/move-ccsprite-around-another-ccsprite-circle-shape). It's for box2d, but you can do it with Chipmunk. If bodyA position will change, orbit will be same. You just need to change speed of body movement for your needs, just increase smoothness and slow down your update method.

Comment: This works great, but the only problem is that if the character's position is set inside the boundingbox of another object, it won't bounce off, but would simply be placed inside that other object.

Comment: This happens because body not moving, just changing it's position. What about `body->SetLinearVelocity(newposition.x, newposition.y)` instead of `body->SetTransform`? Now I can't test will it work or not. Test it and tell me a result.